# Add style to input but only when hovered and inactive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Is there a method of using conditionals to apply a style to my input when it is hovered and not active?

use case:

- Unhovered: Background = white (or no style applied)
- Hovered and **not** active: Background = lightgrey
- Hovered and **is** active: Background = white (or no style applied)

I was thinking of the various attributes of an input that are available within Angular such as `dirty`, `touched` etc..., but I am not sure of how to use them to this effect?

Any pointers would be great.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hover-active-input) with the example html

```css
// This can be used by [ngClass]
.grey {
  background: lightgrey;
}

input:hover {
  background: lightgrey
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)=submit()>
  <input formControlName="myInput" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Changed for you now @Paulie_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not` property, this working snippet might helpful to you.

```css
.test:hover:not(:focus)
{
 background: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Turns out I actually needed the :focus tag, but your theory worked just as well substituting that in :-)

Comment: @physicsboy you can also override the css to look as you want `.CLASSNAME_:hover:focus`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :not()  pseudo-class

```css
pre {
  background: white;
}

pre:hover:not(:active) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Unhovered: Background = white (or no style applied)
Hovered and not active: Background = lightgrey
Hovered and is active: Background = white (or no style applied)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use focus and hover pseudo code.

```css
input:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

input:focus:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```